# What is the lower temperature limit for ion channels function?

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, neurophysiology, electrophysiology

What is the cold-block temperature of ion channels? (not of nerves or axons)

Answer (score 3):

The lower temperature limit of ion channels likely is dependent on various factors, including the type of channel and the recording conditions (tissue type, medium etc.). Reports on the suppression of voltage spikes (i.e., the inhibition of action potential firing) range from 1 to -20<sup>o</sup>C in squid axons, dependent on the species [(Leuchtag, 2008)](https://books.google.nl/books?id=F7gJDmJvqcUC&pg=PA79&lpg=PA79&dq=cold-block+temperature+of+ion+channels?&source=bl&ots=XQ6q9sMbOY&sig=EHnqyBJRFLnVBZI8XwNtP-URl9U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwwuLO-oHLAhXDOQ8KHe_mAOwQ6AEILDAE#v=onepage&q=cold-block%20temperature%20of%20ion%20channels%3F&f=false). I couldn't find information on specific channels.

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Leuchtag, Voltage-Sensitive Ion Channels: Biophysics of Molecular Excitability (2008)](https://books.google.nl/books?id=F7gJDmJvqcUC&pg=PA79&lpg=PA79&dq=cold-block+temperature+of+ion+channels?&source=bl&ots=XQ6q9sMbOY&sig=EHnqyBJRFLnVBZI8XwNtP-URl9U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwwuLO-oHLAhXDOQ8KHe_mAOwQ6AEILDAE#v=onepage&q=cold-block%20temperature%20of%20ion%20channels%3F&f=false)</sub>

Comment: thanks, "suppression of voltage spikes " you mean stopping of action potentials right? The fact that an action potential cannot propagate doesn't mean that the channels are blocked but that the threshold cannot be reached right?

Comment: @george. Yes, correct on the AP firing, I edited the answer to make that more clear. Isn't threshold increase a consequence of inhibition? I.e., I don't follow your dichotomy posed. As a rule, if you find the answer useful, we upvote the question to let others know it's a useful answer. If you think it is *the* answer you can accept it too. You can also downvote it when it's a poor answer.